# Variable names change with R function return

Tags: r, function

I'm new to functions. I'm trying to create one that will aggregate the total number of unique values of one variable by some category. Ex. the number of unique visitors to a store every day.

I was not able to get this to work using ddply, which was my original plan. I was successful, however, using aggregate.  My problem is that I want the variable names to retain their original name, instead of take on the names used in the function (return the column names in the dataframe as day and visitor_id instead of a and b).

I have the a and b in the function because that was the only way I could figure out how to make it look for a variable instead of an object.

```r
data <- data.frame(day = rep(c("Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri"), time=5),
                   visitor_id = c(111,222,333,222,111,222,333,222,222,222,222,111,222,222,333,111,111,222,222,111,222,333,333,333,333))


total_unique <- function(var) {
  x <- length(unique(var))
  return(x)
}

my_function <- function(data, ag_category, var) {
  a <- eval(substitute(ag_category), data)
  b <- eval(substitute(var), data)

  x <- aggregate(b~a, data, FUN=total_unique)

   return(x)
}




test <- my_function(data=data, ag_category=day, var=visitor_id)
```

Also, if anyone can point out what I did wrong with the ddply code, that would also be really helpful!

```
my_function2 <- function(data, ag_category, var) {
  require(plyr)
  a <- eval(substitute(ag_category), data)
  b <- eval(substitute(var), data)


  x <- ddply(data,~a,summarise, length(unique(b)))

  return(x)
}


test2 <- my_function2(data=data, ag_category=day, var=visitor_id)
```

Comment: It seems a bad idea to use "return" as a variable name.

Comment: I agree! It seems a bad idea (hard to read, hard to troubleshoot) to use *any* of the common base R functions as variable names. (But how many times have I created a small, temporary `data.frame` and decided to name it `df`? Difficult habit to break ...)

Comment: Apologies, you're right. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

myFun <- function(data, ag_category, var){
  varname <- quo({{var}})
  data %>%
    group_by({{ag_category}}) %>%
    summarise(!!varname :=  length(unique({{var}})))
}

myFun(data=data, ag_category=day, var=visitor_id)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   day   visitor_id
#>   <fct>      <int>
#> 1 Fri            3
#> 2 Mon            2
#> 3 Thurs          2
#> 4 Tues           3
#> 5 Wed            2
```

Instead of saving the variables as new variables, we use `rlang` from the `tidyverse` to pass the variable name from the function call. We group by the grouping variable and then summarize the unique number of observations.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to pass in the names as symbols, then you need to take extra care to construct the formula you want. Here's one way to do it

```
my_function <- function(data, ag_category, var) {
  ff <- do.call("~", list(substitute(var), substitute(ag_category)))
  x <- aggregate(ff, data, FUN=total_unique)
  return(x)
}
my_function(data=data, ag_category=day, var=visitor_id)
```

It would be even easier if you passed in the names as strings rather then symbols

```
my_function_str <- function(data, ag_category, var) {
  x <- aggregate(reformulate(ag_category, var), data, FUN=total_unique)
  return(x)
}
my_function_str(data=data, ag_category="day", var="visitor_id")
```